# I have to check whether all the elements of an array is equal to one or not...and use it as a while condition...how do i do that?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array....I need to check whether all its elements are equal to one and pass this as a while condition. That is...my code should be executed till all the members of the array becomes one.
My code goes like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>


    using namespace std;




      int main()
     {
         int ele[10];int crd[10];int dist[10]  ; int fid[10] ;
         int a; int i ; int j;int k = 0,l=0  ; //  a is number of villages

        cin>> a ;
        for(i = 0;i<a;i++){
        cin>>ele[i] ;
       }
        for(i=0;i<a;i++){
          cin>>crd[i] ;
       }





     for(k = 0;k<a;k++){
     while(ele[k]= 1){
       for(i=0;i<a;i++){
       if(ele[i] == 0 && ele[i+1] == 1 ){
          dist[l] = std::abs(crd[i+1] - crd[i]) ;
         fid[l] = i ;
        l++ ;


      }else if(ele[i]==1 && ele[i+1] == 0 ){
           dist[l] = std::abs(crd[i+1] - crd[i]) ;
          fid[l] = i + 1;
         l++ ;

        // ele[i+1] = 1
     }

     }



      for(i=0;i<l;i++){
      cout<<fid[i] ;
      }
     for(i=0;i<l;i++){

     cout<<dist[i]<<" " ;

     }

        for(i=0;i<l;i++){
         if(dist[0]>dist[i]){
        swap(dist[0],dist[i]) ;
        ele[fid[i]] = 1 ;
        //swap()

      }else if(l=1){
      ele[fid[0]] = 1 ;
      }
      }

      for(i=0;i<a;i++){
      cout<<ele[i]<<endl ;
    }

     cout<<dist[0] ;
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Please properly format your code

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: else if(l=1){
      ele[fid[0]] = 1 ;
      }
      }

Comment: there is not the problem...the problem is where my while loop starts...i can't execute and stop my code till all the elements of the array becomes one...

Comment: This is not *please debug this for me* community. Try it yourself and ask us about a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in this statement.

```
while(ele[k]= 1)
```

It will always return true as ele[k] is assigned the value 1 which is not 0 leading to an infinite loop. Also there is no need to include so many for loops and while loops. Your condition should be something like:

```
k=0;
while(k < a)
{
    ele[k] = 1;
    k++;
}
```

And there is no need of any for loops at all. Your question does not match with the code you have written. If indeed, you mean to simply replace all values of ele[k] with 1, the above code I have provided should suffice and there would be no use of any other statements in your code. Primarily I believe you should study up while loops and understand how they work essentially. Also, no matter what code the error is in, you should never post unformatted code.